# Method Not Allowed heroku?

Tags: django, python-3.7

haciendo mi primer deploy pero me sale este error, sabeis que podria ser? elimine algunos requerimientos que me daban error entre estos,post,get, y request. sera por esto?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
from .base import *
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['djangoblogcodigopy.herokuapp.com']
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases
```

El error era que había colocado ['djangoblogcodigopy.herokuapp.com'] sin comillas es decir
[djangoblogcodigopy.herokuapp.com] esto me generaba el error method not allowed